# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [676, 540]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, df['Label'], test_size=0.2, random_state=111)
print (X_train.shape) # (540, 4196)
print (X_test.shape) # (136, 4196)
print (y_train.shape) # (540,)
print (y_test.shape) # (136,)
```

When fitting, it gives error:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(features,y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(features)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [676, 540]
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65649990/valueerror-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-151-38).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the features along y_train for the .fit()? I think you are supposed to use X_train instead.

Instead of

```
classifier.fit(features, y_train)
```

Use:

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

You are trying to use two sets of data with different shape, since you did the split earlier. So features has more samples than y_train.

Also, for you predict line. It should be:

```
.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to call the `fit` function with you `X_train`, not with `features`. The error occurs because `features` and `y_train` don't have the same size.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, df['Label'], test_size=0.2, random_state=111)
print (X_train.shape)
print (X_test.shape)
print (y_train.shape)
print (y_test.shape)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

You'll likely also want to call `predict` with `X_test` or `X_train`. You may want to learn a bit more about train/test splits and why they are used.